# Does jQuery $(window).resize() overwrite existing events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does the following jQuery statement overwrite existing functions that have been attached to the DOM window resize event?

```
$(window).resize(function(){doSomething();});
```

Answer (score 2):

No, `$(window).resize` doesn't override any existing event handlers.